# Google-Maps-React: Problems passing props to App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, google-maps, react-props

I'm working on a website and I'd like to use google maps API via Google-Maps-React package.
I've tested it before, as a single application, and I successfully manage to get data back from the API and render it on screen. Now I'm trying to use it on my actual project and it is not working. I imagine that the issue might be that I'm not passing props properly from a component to another.

Any suggestions on how to fix this issue would be very much appreciated. Thank you very much!

Here are my two components and the message I'm getting on the console (Webpack compiled successfully) :

**index.js:139 Uncaught Error: You must include a `google` prop
    at new Map (index.js:139)**

**Venue.js** 
*holds the actual map*

```
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper, Marker } from "google-maps-react";

const mapStyles = {
    width: '100%',
    heigth: '100%',
};

export class MapContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            venues: [
                { lat: 52.471015, lng: 12.719707 }
            ]
        }
    }

    displayMarkers = () => {
        return this.state.venues.map((venue, index) => {
          return <Marker key={index} id={index} position={{
            lat: venue.latitude,
            lng: venue.longitude
          }}
          onClick={() => console.log(this.state.venues)} />
        })
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <Map
           google={this.props.google}
           zoom={8}
           style={mapStyles}
           initialCenter={{ lat: 52.471015, lng: 12.719707 }}
          >
            {this.displayMarkers()}

          </Map>
        );
      }
    }


export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey:''
  })(MapContainer);
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Main from "./main";
import MapContainer from "google-maps-react";


export class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            error: false,
        };        
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("App mounted");

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
                    <Route exact path="/venue" component={MapContainer} />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: did you set the key?

Comment: Try passing `window.google` instead of `this.props.google` to your `Map` component.

Comment: @FábioBCSouza Yes, I did. I just removed it before posting the code here :)

Comment: @SultanH. Just did, but didn't really solve the issue. Thank you very much, though!

Comment: I think that the issue might be on the <Route/>. But to be honest, I've been staring at this code for so long that I can no longer see what's problematic about it.

Comment: You are importing MapContainer from "google-maps-react" but your class is defined is venue.js. try importing MapContainer from venue.js in app.js

Comment: @SameerRezaKhan The Webpack fails to compile when I change it. I believe that since that is a component that belongs to google-maps-react dependencies, I should import it from there, no? Not sure why, but it sure breaks the code if import the function from somewhere else.

Comment: Your code is in venue.js, so it should be imported from there only. Can you share the error generated by webpack, you might be writing the wrong path for venue.js in your App.js

Comment: @SameerRezaKhan here's the message:    
    at Object.parseMaybeConditional (/mnt/c/Users/pc/desktop/weddingproject/my-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9056:23)
 @ ./src/start.js 4:0-28 20:25-28
 @ multi @babel/polyfill ./src/start.js
webpack: Failed to compile.

Comment: I think there might be some other issue then, cz if you are trying to use any component, you need to import from that file only

Comment: @SameerRezaKhan Thank you very much! I'm having a look at start.js, the component that the webpack is complaining about.

Comment: Also remove " export " keyword before class in venue.js as you are exporting it as default at the bottom of file.

Comment: @LuisaSilva, you are welcome, Is there any progress? please update ur question if there is.

Comment: @SultanH. Kind of... Webapack still is unhappy with Venue.js: 
```ERROR in ./src/venue.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /mnt/c/Users/pc/desktop/weddingproject/my-app/src/venue.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (20:20):

  18 |     }
  19 |
> 20 |     displayMarkers = () => {
     |                    ^
  21 |       return this.state.venues.map((venue, index) =>{
  22 |         return <Marker key={index} id={index} position={{
  23 |           lat: venue.latitude,```

Comment: Do u have a custom webpack config or is it the CRA's?

Comment: @SultanH. I have CRA's webpack config.

Comment: @SultanH. It works nowwwwwww! I'm using the boilerplate code of the package and it runs. I'd love to know what was problematic about my code, but I'm running out of time now. I'll definitely do it once I'm done. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Lol, I'm glad Luisa, well, weird things happen! you may submit the answer below and I can take a look sometime Today and try to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Because your import MapContainer path is incorrect !

in your `App.js` file change :

```
import MapContainer from "google-maps-react";
```

to your MapContainer component like :

```
import MapContainer from "./components/Venue.js";
```

simple demo : [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/google-maps-react-gmdes)

Comment: Hello! I just changed it, but now I'm having issues with the webpack no compiling: at Object.parseStatementContent (/mnt/c/Users/pc/desktop/weddingproject/my-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:10794:27)
 @ ./src/app.js 22:0-38 55:19-31
 @ ./src/start.js
 @ multi @babel/polyfill ./src/start.js
webpack: Failed to compile.

Comment: I added your code in codesandbox, see answer simple demo, you have to check your source maybe need stop and start your npm if you haven't any problem in your source, ( answer updated ) just need apiKey

Comment: I could be that I will have to import and implement the API codes on my source. I'm gonna try to do it now. Thank you so much!